# Javascript - Run a code nonstopable via Chrome Console including refreshing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, triggers, settimeout

I want to run a javascript code via the Chrome's Console.

```
var word_idx = 0;
var interval_per_word = 250; // in milliseconds
function DoIT(){
    if(word_idx<words.length){
        $('#inputfield').val(words[word_idx] + ' ');
        var keyup = jQuery.Event('keyup');
        keyup.which = 32;
        $('#inputfield').trigger(keyup);
        word_idx++;
        setTimeout('DoIT()', interval_per_word);
    }
}
DoIT();
```

Now, I'm trying to do that every minute, the code will refresh the page and use the function "DoIT" again.

Any help? I can't think of any idea, tried using location.refresh() with no success.

I'll be glad for help, thanks!

Comment: have you try `setInterval`?

Comment: note that if you refresh the page, you don't need to make your function recursive...

Comment: What other reason(s) are there for refreshing the page?

Comment: Well, I don't have an idea how to keep the code running when refreshing, AND activating "DoIT" again.

Comment: setInterval(DoIT(),60000); ?

Comment: The problem is, after I reload, the code won't keep running.

Comment: The Chrome console resets every time you reload the page. You are starting from scratch --- there is a way to preserve everything that has been logged, but any actively running code will be shut down. If you want something permanent, try Tampermonkey, which will run every time the page loads. Using external resources you can also permanently store variables as well. Tampermonkey link ---> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en